# Just showing a domain name in the address bar even though real page is located on another domain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, handlers

I do not know were to start for this, although I think it has to to with handlers - here is what I want to do:

Some of my clients own their domain name but they use my plate-form with it's own domain name to showcase their products (they get a unique url with id number). I want the address bar to show their domain names instead of mine.

So let's say they own www.example.com and I want visitors to end up on www.example2.com/234 but I want www.example.com to show (permanantly) in the address bar, even if visitors browse on different pages.

What should be the approach after the domain DNS or forward part?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why don't you want to forward?

Comment: You could use `mod_proxy`, but it would be slow and inefficient.

Comment: What do you mean? just forwarding example.com to example1.com/234 will do the trick? (showing example.com in the address bar)?